# A better way to get the last character

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have been working in an exercise, I have 2 values (one with 9 characters and the other with 8) and I have to show 3 columns.

1. The original number
2. The number without the last character
3. Only the last character

The Query works but I would like to know a way to improve how I get the last column, I used a Case clause but I think there´s a better procedure to accomplish the same thing.
Thank you.

```
select rut, 
   SUBSTR(RUT, 1, LENGTH(RUT)-1) as RUT_SD,
   case when  length(rut) = 9 then 
              SUBSTR(RUT, 9, LENGTH(RUT)-1) 
        when  length(rut) = 8 then
              SUBSTR(RUT, 8, LENGTH(RUT)-1) 
        end as DV

from (select '244447232' rut union all
      select '3446545k')
```

Comment: Check out the [documentation on `SUBSTR()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr). If the `position` argument is supplied with a negative number it will determine the postion from the end of the string. So *"3. Only the last character"* could be solved simply with `SUBSTR(rut, -1)`.

Comment: Thank you jnevill it works, i will keep this in mind and read more about substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below few options

```
select rut, 

  regexp_extract(rut, r'(.+).$'),
  regexp_extract(rut, r'(.)$'),

  substr(rut, 1, length(rut) - 1),
  substr(rut, -1)

from (
  select '244447232' rut union all
  select '3446545k'
)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Test the query, and yes the result is the same, still I’m not familiar with the way you used regexp_extract and it´s syntax, I mean I don´t know what   “   r'(.+).$'   ” and  “   r'(.)$'    ” stands for. 
Thank you for the knowledge

Comment: check out [regular expression syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) that is used here. meantime  - `r'(.+).$'` literally says: retrieve/extract all/any chars but the last one! and   `r'(.)$'` says - retrive only the very last char (whatever it is)